# Registering class types using DI Container

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I want to register some of classes which will be used by multiple different objects.
It's hard to explain, but each of those registered classes have own "identifier" so I must registed it manually

Here is registration part: (Startup.cs)

```
WebSocketHandler.AddHandler<ChatHandler>("/api/chat");
```

Registration method (manually created instances):

```
public static void AddHandler<T>(string path) where T: new()
{
    var handler = new T() as IWebSocketHandler;
    handlers.Add(path, handler);
}
```

But ChatHandler is used by another object, e.g ChatService

```
public ChatService(IChatHandler handler)
{
    _handler = handler;
}
```

The other problem is that the ChatHandler is descendent of WebSockethandler which requires WebSocketManager instance in constructor.

How I can register objects like ChatHandler without manually crateing instances?

Comment: Do you want `ChatHandler` class to be registered in the DI Container?

Comment: Yep, it would be greate

Comment: Have you tried to use for example `services.AddTransient<ClassNameHere, ClassNameHere>();`?

Comment: Problem solved - I modified registration code to:
WebSocketHandler.RegisterHandler<IChatHandler>("/api/chat", app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IChatHandler>());
and registration method body to: 
_handlers.Add(path, handler as IWebSocketHandler);